# "Access to the path is denied" to my custom activities assembly in temp when loading build definition Process parameters

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Steps:

1. Open build definition "test1" which points to build controller "controller1" on "builder1" machine, then click "Process" tab
2. Open build definition "test2" which points to build controller "controller2" on "builder2" machine, then click "Process" tab

**Error is: Team Foundation Error Access to the path {path}is denied**:

[image]

Noteworthy: I also get errors in output window, for example:

```
Summary: There were 0 failures, 6 errors and 0 warnings loading custom activities and services.
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Error: API restriction: The assembly 'file:///C:\Users\{!REDACTED!}\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\df2044d9-c8bb-4666-9c93-513e149cd3e0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.
```

I have not proven the two errors are associated (I also get similar API restriction errors ANY time I load process parameters), however they could be.

The reason I have this two-controller setup is because controller1 uses a path to my custom activities ie $/Process/Dev and controller2 uses path $/Process/Production. It helps me test my changes in isolation.

**So the question is:** Is there something I am missing with regards to Microsoft's support for using more than one build controller (on separate machines) pointing to the same TFS instance?

Or, I'm open to different ideas on how to test my changes to my custom activities without forcing all of my builds to point to the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your BuildTasks.dll is different in both locations. i would either update the dll to the latest version in whatever location is wrong or point both controllers to the same dll, you could also ensure that the dll has different version numbers if you want to maintain different source locations. Multiple controllers are supported and work well normally.

As a short term fix, clear cache between opening different build definitions so the 2 different dll's don't clash with each other

> The reason I have this two-controller setup is because controller1
>   uses a path to my custom activities ie $/Process/Dev and controller2
>   uses path $/Process/Production. It helps me test my changes in
>   isolation.

it's not clear which machine your opening the Build Definitions on but I'll assume it's your development machine, I always place my buildtasks.dll in the public folder of Visual Studio when I'm developing.

Comment: Would your answer change if I told you the BuildTasks.dll was same (same checksum for example)? Currently, I believe I have Dev and Production equalized

Comment: maybe.. ;-) what TFS version are you on?  out of interest did clearing cache / app data give any improvement